# One To One Relationship in JPA (AppEngine)

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

In my Profile class I have

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private ProfilePicture profilePic = null;
```

My method in updating the profilePic

```
public Profile updateUserProfilePic(Profile user) {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Profile userx = em.find(Profile.class, user.getEmailAddress());
    userx.setProfilePic( user.getProfilePic() );

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return userx;
}
```

When updateUserProfilePic is called, it just add another profilePic in datastore, it doesn't replaced the existing profilePic. Is my implementation correct? I want to update the profilePic of profile.

Comment: and user.getProfilePic is in what state ? detached ? transient ? "JDOHelper.getObjectState(obj)" tells you. And the version of GAE JPA you're using is ?

Comment: JDOHelper.getObjectState(userx.getProfilePic()) returns transient, im using JPA 1.0, GAE 1.6.4. What does transient mean?

Answer (score 1):

"Transient" means not persistent and not detached.

Using that version of GAE JPA you need a detached or managed object there if you want it to reuse the existing object.

Using v2 of Googles plugin there is a persistence property that allows merge of a transient object that has "id" fields set.